# Openshift wildfly cartridge standalone.xml vs Java EE 7 Web Profile

Tags: openshift, wildfly, wildfly-8

Why does openshift wildfly cartridge standalone.xml file contain subsystems which are not part of Java EE Web profile specification (checked for 8 & 9 version) such as these ones ?

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jacorb"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jsr77"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>
```

Indeed, standalone.xml file is normally used for Web Profile and does not contain these configurations in Wildfly distribution. They are declared in standalone-full.xml. 
See this page: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Getting+Started+Guide?_sscc=t#GettingStartedGuide-WildFly8Configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that is a community cartridge (not supported by the OpenShift Online team) I would suggest that you:

1. Log an issue on the github repo for that cartridge
2. Try posting the issue to one of the WildFly developer email lists

As both options should get you in touch with someone who is well qualified to answer your question or update the cartridge if there is indeed an issue with it.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that